# Returning values based on a conditional having

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to return values from the uid column based on each uid appearing at least once with 2 different categoric variables:

```
+--------+--------+---------+
|  uid   |  type  | period  |
+--------+--------+---------+
| abc123 | event1 | control |
| abc123 | event1 | test    |
| def456 | event1 | control |
| def456 | event1 | control |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

In this case `abc123` would return a count of 2 for event1, as the uid appears in both the test period and the control period, `def456` would not return a count as it only occurs during one period, giving the intermediary table of:

```
+--------+-----------+
|  uid   | typecount |
+--------+-----------+
| abc123 |         2 |
+--------+-----------+
```

This is my code so far:

```
with cb as(
  select uid, count(type) as cbuffercount, period
    from `AJG.ABV_buff_wperiods`
    where type="bufferStart" and seq>12 and not uid="null" and not uid="" and period="control"
    group by uid, period
    having count(uid)>1),
tb as(
  select uid, count(type) as tbuffercount, period
    from `AJG.ABV_buff_wperiods`
    where type="bufferStart" and seq>12 and not uid="null" and not uid="" and period="test"
    group by uid, period
    having count(uid)>1),
ci as(
  select uid, count(instance) as cinstancecount, period
    from `AJG.ABV_buff_wperiods`
    where seq>12 and not uid="null" and not uid="" and period="control"
    group by uid, period
    having count(uid)>1),
ti as(
    select uid, count(instance) as tinstancecount, period
    from `AJG.ABV_buff_wperiods`
    where seq>12 and not uid="null" and not uid="" and period="test"
    group by uid, period
    having count(uid)>1)
select uid, cb.cbuffercount, tb.tbuffercount, ci.cinstancecount, ti.tinstancecount,
cb.cbuffercount-tb.tbuffercount as absbufferddx, (cb.cbuffercount/ci.cinstancecount)-(tb.tbuffercount/tb.tinstancecount) as proportionalbufferddx
from
  cb join tb
  using(uid)
where
  cb.uid=tb.uid
order by absbufferddx desc
```

I'm also having an additional issue where Bigquery is not recognising the last 2 tables I defined in the `with` clause when I try to select variables from them (e.g. `ci.cinstancecount`). I ran a query including `cb` and `tb` just fine. No idea why adding 2 extra tables breaks it?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want *as a text table*.  Your sample data and your query don't really make sense -- the query is really complicated and it is unclear what the relationship is to the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select uid, count(distinct period)
from t
group by uid
having count(distinct period) >= 2;
```

If you want to count both `event` and `period`, then I am going to recommend string munging.  BigQuery doesn't support `count(distinct)` on either arrays or structs, so you might as well do:

```
select uid, count(distinct concat(event, '|', period))
from t
group by uid
having count(distinct concat(event, '|', period)) >= 2;
```

Comment: It was specifically the having clause I wanted to add it to, so the uid has to occur at least once with a control and a test in period, so could I use a case clause to count uid if the distinct period=2?

The count(type) is what I want, but I only want to count those based on the above conditions.